# Open PDF in browser instead of Downloading

Tags: pdf, contentversion, files

Using

```
sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!id}
```

in URL to download PDF files from ContentVersion in a public site.

Is there anyway to get a PDF file to open in a browser instead of Downloading it after clicking the URL.

Comment: Where does this url come from?

Comment: For example:
https://myDomain.force.com/mySite/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/xxxxxxxxxxxxQAQ
The download link works just fine, the problem is that browser downloads the file straight away. I need it to be opened in browser instead.

Comment: It depends on the browser you use. With Google Chrome, the pdf is opened in the browser, not downloaded. If you want to show it on the browser, you can use an iframe like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser

Comment: The problem is that the file comes from Salesforce servlet and it's not a straight link to the file like something.pdf. Somehow I guess I should catch first whatever comes from the download link and if it's a pdf then show it like in the example you showed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was actually solved by setting the pdf filetype to 'Execute in Browser' from
Setup -> Security -> File Upload and Download Security

Comment: Thank you sir!!